# I have DBConcurencyExeption after I tried to delete 2 rows

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, ado.net, dataset

I'm using `DataSet` and `DataAdapter` in my program. In my database I wrote a stored procedure called `DeleteTheme`:

```
     ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteTheme]
     @Theme nchar(50)
     AS
     DELETE setOfThemes
     FROM  
     setOfThemes INNER JOIN themes
     ON setOfThemes.number=themes.ID
     WHERE themes.thema=@Theme
```

In C# I can delete rows from a `DataGrid` using this code:

```
    private void ThemeDataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            DataRow dr = myDataSet.Tables["themes"].NewRow();
            dr = myDataSet.Tables["themes"].Rows[numberOfRow];
            dr.Delete();
        }
    }
```

After that I use button update with this code:

```
        adapter.DeleteCommand = adapterCommands.DeleteTheme();
        adapter.Update(myDataSet, "themes");
```

and I it causes an exception

> DBConcurencyExeption
>   Concurrency violation: the DeleteCommand
>   affected 0 of the expected 1 records."

whats wrong with it?

(I deleted 2 rows after click update button)

Answer (score 0):

From the code sample you seem to be adding a row to the `DataTable` by calling the `NewRow()` method. Don't you want to mark the data row as deleted by calling the `Delete()` method. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/feh3ed13%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) may help.